# What do the item colors in Torchlight II mean?

Tags: torchlight-2

I started to play Torchlight II few days ago, and I don't usually play this type of games, so I don't know how good are the "colored" items. I know that the white/green are the "basics" but not the other colors, so can someone tell me from the worst to the best (white, green...) colors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While item colors in such games usually follow a similar pattern they can be quite different from game to game.

Torchlight 2 uses the following pattern:

- **White (Common):** This are standard item, usually without any special properties or bonuses.
- **Green (Enchanted):** These items have at least one magical property/bonus.
- **Blue (Rare):** These items usually offer more different bonuses compared to enchanted items.
- **Gold (Unique):** Unique items are fixed, premade items you can find. These will always feature the same bonuses as well as a special name.
- **Orange (Legendary):** These items are limited to weapons/shields only and are otherwise similar to unique items; just even more rare and powerful.